# How to run 3 thread groups in loops using Jmeter?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am new to Jmeter. Here is one thing that is puzzling me
I have 3 thread groups

I want to run these set of thread group multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not something you can do at least with [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

The only option I can think of is executing your [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) multiple times providing the same [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) as the output and the results from the next iterations will be appended

Something like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl # loop1
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl # loop2
etc.
```